# How to delete a folder in remote Windows from Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, shell, delete-directory

I am running automation tests on both local (Linux) and remote Selenium node (Windows). And I want to delete a folder created during test, using Java `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`. It works fine on local (Linux), but I have a hard time to figure out how to do it on Windows node. The following is my attempts:

```
try {
    if (rBundle.getString("RUN_ON").equalsIgnoreCase("local")) // delete folder temp on local (Linux) - it works
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -rf " + System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Temp");
    else // delete folder C:/Temp on remote Windows
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -rf IEUser@10.2.2.240/C/Temp");
        // Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -rf //10.2.2.240/C/Temp");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I try to delete folder C:/Temp on the remote Windows, but I don't have any success. I don't get any Exceptions, it went though that block. Obviously the command line is wrong, but I have no idea.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You just need to find a command line that works, which you can do in your shell, and then `exec()` that in your Java code. It isn't a Java question at all, it is a Linux and Windows question, and probably off-topic as being more suited to superuser.com.

Comment: @EJP thanks for your hint

Comment: Building a bit on EJP's comment, if you really want to be able to do this from the Linux box, your probably want to set up Samba on that machine.

Comment: You could try to execute the command over ssh which would make the command `ssh IEUser@10.2.2.240 "rm -rf /C/Temp"`. If you don't have an ssh server setup on your Windows machine a cygwin is one possible solution with many online setup guides.

Comment: When you say your are using Selenium, I assume you are testing a Website in two different servers,  right?

Comment: @Isma So, my workspace (Automation code) is in Linux, testing a Website. It runs on local (my Linux) and on a Selenium node, which is Windows.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info, I added another possible way of doing this, directly from the Web server so you can avoid the hassle of executing remote commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to achieve this could be to do it directly from the Web server by adding a method to your Website to clean resources.

For example: http://your_server/clean_resources

Then, just use Java to delete the folder:

```
// You could pass a parameter to the URL to know if it's windows  
// or linux and set the path accordingly
String path = "c:/temp";

Path directory = Paths.get(path);
    Files.walkFileTree(directory, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            Files.delete(file);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc)
                throws IOException {
            Files.delete(dir);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
```

Finally, using Selenium, just navigate to this URL when you finish your test.

```
driver.get("http://your_server/clean_resources");
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a near solution, I can get rid of command line

Answer (score 1):

in Windows try

```
rmdir directoryname /s /q
```

as per documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rd

/s  Deletes a directory tree (the specified directory and all its subdirectories, including all files).
/q  Specifies quiet mode. Does not prompt for confirmation when deleting a directory tree. (Note that /q works only if /s is specified.)

How do you run this Windows command from a Linux station... good question

Answer (score 1):

Originally added this as a comment but upgrading to an Answer for more visibility.

Execute the rm command on the Windows server over ssh. This will require you setting up an ssh server on Windows, cygwin looks to be one of the best options. Once you has the ssh server setup executing the remote rm command will use the command `ssh IEUser@10.2.2.240 "rm -rf /cygdrive/c/Temp"`.

Answer (score 1):

rm is a command for Linux command line equivalent command on windows is del command:

```
    C:\>del /?
    Deletes one or more files.

    DEL [/P] [/F] [/S] [/Q] [/A[[:]attributes]] names
    ERASE [/P] [/F] [/S] [/Q] [/A[[:]attributes]] names

      names         Specifies a list of one or more files or directories.
                    Wildcards may be used to delete multiple files. If a
                    directory is specified, all files within the directory
                    will be deleted.

      /P            Prompts for confirmation before deleting each file.
      /F            Force deleting of read-only files.
      /S            Delete specified files from all subdirectories.
      /Q            Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to delete on global wildcard
      /A            Selects files to delete based on attributes
      attributes    R  Read-only files            S  System files
            H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
            I  Not content indexed Files  L  Reparse Points
            -  Prefix meaning not
```

To delete a folder use:

```
      DEL /F /S /Q /A "Full Path of Folder\*"
```

[Reference: sevenforums](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/55728-file-delete-command-prompt.html)